# What can cause a 500 error in a HttpResponse to an AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, django

**EDIT** mayor changes were made to the question and text to make it clear. As it turns out the error is caused by a very stupid mistake which is that I forgot to import HttpResponse to my views.py. Since in the same views.py I handle another view, I assumed it was imported. Rookie mistake. :(

**Question:**
I'm attempting to submit up or down votes via ajax. Apparently most of the code in my view is executed, then when returning a response it fails. The problem is that there are no errors displayed by django; the only info I get in the terminal is this: "POST /c/vote/ HTTP/1.1" 500 10814. Where /c/vote/ is the URL that should handle votes.

The console in Chrome doesn't help much either. The error I get is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)", then if I click the link I'm redirected to /c/vote/ where django returns a 404. **Note** I'm voting in a different url (i.e. `/c/<country>/`)

I found out that votes are actually being saved, or deleted so the problem may be when returning a response.

My template (custom template tags to know if the user voted before):

```
<div class="vote_buttons" x:id="{{linkpost.pk}}">
    <a href="#" class="upVote{% if linkpost|is_up_voted_by:user %} voted{%endif%}" x:value="1" ></a>
    <a href="#" class="downVote{% if linkpost|is_down_voted_by:user %} voted{%endif%}" x:value="-1"></a>
```

The js code (I'm using JQuery). The variable {{ vote_url }} is passed with a template tag.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".vote_buttons").bind("vote", function(event, value) {
            var vote_el = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                url: '{{ vote_url }}',
                data: {

                    'pk': vote_el.attr("x:id"),
                    'delta': value
                },
                dataType: "json",
        success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    switch (data.voted_as) {
                        case 1:
                            vote_el.find("a.upVote").addClass("voted");
                            vote_el.find("a.downVote").removeClass("voted");
                       break;
                        case -1:
                            vote_el.find("a.upVote").removeClass("voted");
                            vote_el.find("a.downVote").addClass("voted");
                       break;
                    }
                },
            });
        });
        $('.upVote, .downVote').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().trigger("vote", $(this).attr("x:value"));
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

And finally the view. I added some print statements to figure out where does it fails. Thanks to @Steven the code executes all the way to Step 12. Then the previously mentioned error occurs.

```
def vote(request):
    """
    Likes or dislikes a linkpost.
    """
    print "Setp 1 ok!"
    #User must be authenticated to vote.
    if request.is_ajax():
        print "Step 2 ok"
        if request.method == 'POST' and request.user.is_authenticated():
            print "Step 3 ok"
            delta = request.POST['delta']
            # In case an error occurrs with delta value
            try:
                delta = int(delta)
                print "Step 4 ok"
            except ValueError:
                print "Error was value error"
                return HttpResponse("{'success': 'false'}")

            # You can only vote upwards or downwards    
            if not delta in (1, -1):
                print "Error was in delta"
                return HttpResponse("{'success': 'false'}")
            print "Step 5 ok"
            #We check if the linkpost actually exists!
            LinkPost = get_model('company', 'LinkPost')
            try:
                linkpost = LinkPost.objects.get(pk=request.POST['pk'])
                print "Step 6 ok"
            except LinkPost.DoesNotExist:
                print "Link object does not exist"
                return HttpResponse("{'success': 'false'}")

            #We check if the user voted before.
            Vote = get_model('company', 'Vote')
            try:
                vote = Vote.objects.get(linkpost = linkpost, listener = request.user)
                print "Step 7 ok!" 
            except Vote.DoesNotExist:
                print "Vote doesn't exists!" 
                vote = None

            # If there is already a vote
            if vote:

                print "Step 8."
                if vote.delta == delta:
                    vote.delete()
                else:
                    print "Step 9."
                    vote.delta = delta
                    vote.save()

            #There wasn't a vote, we create one.
            else:
                print "Step 10."
                Vote.objects.create(linkpost = linkpost,
                                           listener = request.user,
                                           delta = request.POST['delta'])

            response_dict = {'success' : 'true', 'voted_as': delta}          
            print "Step 12."    
            return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict), mimetype="application/json")
        else:
            print "User not authenticated"
            raise Http404('What are you doing here?')
    else:
        print "Request isn't ajax"
        raise Http404('What are you doing here?')
```

Any help figuring out the problem will be highly appreciated! If the question is still unclear I'll try to clarify or add as much info as possible!

Comment: I can not see where do you pass a `{{ vote_url }}` variable to the template. Does your ajax request adresses correctly?

Comment: Hi, Sorry! I'm very new to this and couldn't find a way to trace the error. Edited my question to show the error and how I pass vote_url to template.

Comment: Keep editing the question. You don't need to bother marking out what each edit is. Go nuts and reformat the whole thing if that makes it clearer. The primary goal is make the question obvious enough for someone to quickly understand it.  You're still far too confused/confusing to have a real question.  It's very common that the exercise of laying out the question neatly improves your own understanding of what's going on that you can work it out yourself; or get a helpful answer. Ensure debugging is on so you can see the cause of the 500 error.

Comment: Align/cleanup the code so that it will be easy for others to understand your question and help you better. Update the question when you find some improvement.

Comment: Thanks guys, I hope everything is much clear now. If it's still unclear please let me know so I can make appropriate changes.

Comment: Also, your response_dict is actually a string. You are then using simplejson to convert this string to json: this may not be what you want, you probably want response_dict to be a dict before doing this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
response_dict = "{'success' : 'true', 'voted_as': '%s'}" % (delta)
```

You have an extraneous s after the % operator in your code. It should be `% (delta)`

Also, you should find that you can see Django's informative error page in your browser developer tools (check the Network section), assuming you have DEBUG=True set. The formatting may be off, but it should still help you get to the code errors more quickly.

---

Edit: OP fixed typo detailed below:

If this isn't a typo in your question: `except Vote.DoesNotExists:`

then you may have more luck with:

```
except Vote.DoesNotExist:
```

Comment: Hi, good eye. Apparently it wasn't the may problem, but it helped to figure out that most of the code in view was being executed. Thnks!

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped a lot. The code now executes all the way to step 12! I'm updating the question since I believe the problem is that once the HttpResponse is returned the JS code can't figure out which css elements to modify. Perhaps I need to return more info in the dictionary or modify the js.

Comment: @JaimeVaqueiroT. As I noted in my comment on your question, you are JSON encoding a string, where you probably want to JSON encode a dictionary. Try `response_dict = {'success':True, 'voted_as': delta}` instead.

Comment: updated question with the dictionary actually being a dictionary. Still the same problem...

Comment: @Steven... just found out what the problem was. I feel stupid. Besides the mistakes you adequately pointed out I forgot to import HttpResponse to my views.py. This was causing the 500 error. I really appreciate your help. Thanks.